# Why not use pointer to pointer when reversing a string?

Tags: c, function, pointers, scope

I have seen this code:

```
void reverse_string(char *str)
{
    /* skip null */
    if (str == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    /* skip empty string */
    if (*str == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    /* get range */
    char *start = str;
    char *end = start + strlen(str) - 1; /* -1 for \0 */
    char temp;

    /* reverse */
    while (end > start)
    {
        /* swap */
        temp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = temp;

        /* move */
        ++start;
        --end;
    }
}
```

And I don't understand why a pointer to a pointer is not passed in the function.  How can it be reversed then, if a copy of the passed pointer is made inside the function?  How are the changes being propagated outside?

Comment: Think about what the pointer is pointing to. That place is the same in this function and the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can it be reversed then, if a copy of the passed pointer is made
>   inside the function? How are the changes being propagated outside

It works because you're making changes **in the memory pointed by that pointer**. So after the function ends the pointer still points where it used to, but the contents (the order of the characters) has changed. In other words, there's no need to change the address `str` points to.

Answer (score 1):

The memory contents of the `char *` array are modified in place.

Answer (score 0):

The string is being reversed in place.  That is, the pointer to the string stays the same, but the string it points to is reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the while loop you will see that the string is reversed in-place.

```
   while (end > start)
    {
        /* swap */
        temp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = temp;

        /* move */
        ++start;
        --end;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reversing a string is **not an operation on the pointer**. It's an operation on the data that is **being pointed by the pointer**. That's the reason the pointer itself can be passed by value to the function, i.e. inside the function it's actually a copy of the pointer that was passed to the function - it's ok since there is no need to modify the pointer, just the pointed data.